# Adding a two simple JLabels to a jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, layout-manager

I have searched everywhere, and there is tons of documentation, but is is all confusing, and half of the test code doesn't work, so I am asking. what is the simplest way to make a jlabel, set its location (with ints or a dimension), and add it to the JFrame

```
package com.notelek.notify;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Gui {



    public static void main(String[] args){

    }

    public static void notify(String line1, String line2, String imagepath, int style){
        GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
        int swidth = width - 320;

        JFrame notification = new JFrame();
        notification.setSize(new Dimension(320,64));
        notification.setLocation(swidth, 0);
        notification.setUndecorated(true);
        notification.setVisible(true);

        JPanel main = new JPanel();

        JLabel notifyline1 = new JLabel();
        notifyline1.setText("test");
        notifyline1.setLocation(0, 0);
        main.add(notification);
    }

}
```

Comment: You never add your label to any container, so how can it show up anyhwere?

Comment: @us2012 please make this am answer (maybe with a small example) so I can further up vote it

Comment: You don't need `GraphicsEnvironment`, replace `notification.setLocation(swidth, 0);` with `notification.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl The OP is using `GraphicsEnvironment` to determine the width of the screen and align it to the right edge, while `setLocationRelativeTo` will center the frame...good idea or bad, not my place to say - nice suggestion though

Comment: just ignore the inputs, I was experimenting with different methods of getting text to the screen, forgot to take those out

Comment: *"what is the simplest way to .. set its location (with ints or a dimension)"*  Simple in this case results in 'broken GUI'.  ***Use layouts.***  *"half of the test code doesn't work"*  So use code from the other half.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean `notification.add(main);` and order is important:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        notify("", "", "", 0);
    }

    public static void notify(String line1, String line2, String imagepath, int style){
        JFrame notification = new JFrame();
        JPanel main = new JPanel();
        JLabel notifyline1 = new JLabel();
        notifyline1.setText("test");
        main.add(notifyline1);
        notification.add(main);
        notification.setSize(new Dimension(320,64));
        notification.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        notification.setUndecorated(true);
        notification.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: no need to call the method (doing that in another class) but it works! how would I add 2 lines of text though?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your `JLabel` to a visible container, otherwise it cannot show up on the screen.

I also guess that you actually intended to add your `JPanel` to your `JFrame` rather than vice versa - something like that:

```
...
main.add(notifyline1);
...    
notification.add(main);
...
```